# is it possible to restart or reset a vagrant instance created by test-kitchen?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, test-kitchen

Sometimes I have to reboot or end my session mid testing on a machine.

As it can take ages to do a full converge it would be great to just be able to start or stop a machine like I would using vagrant commands.

Is this possible with machines created with test kitchen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it right now is to:

> cd to the directory for your vm inside .kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/yourinstancehere and issue a vagrant reload command, that should restart your VM

Source: https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/issues/115#issuecomment-52943418